# How to chart multiple timelines in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I need to make a graph in Excel of people's time serving in a position, their start date to end date.  I'm trying to get their names on the Y axis, and then a horizontal line for each name running from their start date to their end date.

I can't figure out how to create this type of chart.

Answer (score 4):

If you really want names on the y-axis, you need to use a Bar Chart.  This gets a bit tricky.  First you need to set up your data with a "Length of Employment" Column, as shown in the table below:

[image]

The Length column is just the end date minus the start date.  Then select the names and the first two columns (Start and Length), and choose "Stacked Bar Chart" from the Chart tab.  You'll probably have to click "Switch Row/Column" from the Chart>Source Data... menu to get a graph with just two data series.

Select the first series and format it to have "No Fill", "No Line" and uncheck "Shadow".  This makes the first series invisible.  (It is only there to take up the space before the Start Date).  Next format the x-axis scale to have a minimum and maximum appropriate for your data.  You should end up with something similar to this:

[image]

(Names shamelessly stolen from @Gary's Student :)

Comment: I like this better than my solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

I mocked this out in Excel using three columns; Name, Start Date and End Date. I added four names with start and end dates for each person. I highlighted the data (A1 to C5) and pressed <kbd>F11</kbd>. I then changed the graph type to "Scatter with straight lines and markers", and I then edited the data source so Legend Entries (series) was the Names column, with Start Date and End Date on the Horizontal Axis.

What I ended up with was names across the bottom, dates on the left with earliest date at the bottom, and a line from the start to end date for each of the four people.

Refer to the image below.

[image: Scatter Diagram of Names with Start and End Dates]

Answer (score 0):

I did this in LibreOffice Calc rather than Excel so the menu options are a little different, but I'll describe it generically and you should be able to find the same settings in Excel.

[image]

The data is set up with the start and end dates in column A as the X values.  Each person is a separate series in columns B through D.  I gave each person a dummy Y value to provide a horizontal line for each.  Use the highest dummy value for the leftmost name to get the legend in the same order as the lines.

Select the XY (scatter) chart with points and lines.

To make the formatting pretty:

- Set the Y axis major and minor intervals to 1 so you only get grid lines for each name (or even eliminate the horizontal grid lines).  Deselect the Y axis labeling so the dummy values don't show.
- Set the X axis date formating to a short form and rotate the labels (I used 45 degrees), so that they don't run into each other.
- You can customize the rest of the appearance as desired.

I used the legend for simplicity, but the names could be added to the Y axis instead using text boxes.