# How to alter the horizontal axis labels on a bar graph to show a year long timeline?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts

My ideal graph has names down the vertical axis, with a bar graph showing at what date their roles will conclude; I want the horizontal axis to simple have a year-long timeline, but excel automatically picks what dates it thinks make the most sense. Help ?

Comment: You can manually control the X axis minimum, maximum and major and minor divisions.  You can also rotate the axis label text so that the long date text doesn't run together.  Right-click on the axis to access the settings.  What problem are you encountering when you do that?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1254204/how-to-chart-multiple-timelines-in-excel/1254225#1254225

Comment: It may be echoed above, but check that the horizontal axis is formatted to "Text".

Comment: In some versions of Excel (2011 Mac at least) the trick is that you have to enter the min and max dates as date serial numbers.  That is the number of days since Jan 1, 1900.  The easiest way to find what numbers you need to enter is to type your min and max dates into cells and then format them as numbers.  For example, Jan 1, 2017 is 42736.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just a matter of formatting, but there's little info in your OP.  Try clicking the X Axis, and format to "Text":

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether your version of Excel is as irritating as mine when it comes to getting reasonably spaced dates as axis labels.  Here's how I formatted the graph from my answer to your [previous question](https://superuser.com/questions/1254204/how-to-chart-multiple-timelines-in-excel) to show one year of date labels.

1. Format the x-axis *scale* to have a minimum of 42736, max of 43102, and major unit of 61. This gives the graph below. The day of the month wanders around because of the different number of days in a month.

[image]

2. Then format the x-axis *number* to be Date with Type Mar-01. This gives the graph shown below.  If you need each month labeled, you can stretch the graph wider and set the major unit to 30 or 31.

[image]